# I need to assign a value of java-script variable inside in function into php variable in a same file

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I need to get the total value inside the computeTotalDistance() function into php variable. I tried it many ways but was pointless.

```
            var rendererOptions = {
                draggable: true
            };
            var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
            ;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var map;

            var Srilanka = new google.maps.LatLng(6.9344, 79.8428);

            function initialize() {

                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: Srilanka
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

                google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function () {
                    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
                });

                calcRoute();
            }

            function calcRoute() {

                var locations = ['Galle', 'Kandy', 'minneriya wildlife park', 'Horton Plains'];

                var waypoints = locations.map(function(loc) {
                    return { 'location': loc };
                });

                var request = {
                    origin: 'Colombo',
                    destination: 'Colombo',
                    waypoints: waypoints,
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                };


                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    }
                });
            }

            function computeTotalDistance(result) {
                var total = 0;
                var myroute = result.routes[0];
                for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                }
                total = total / 1000.0;
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
```

I used following one, but I confused with how to catch return value with it.

```
 <?php
      $tot = echo "<script>document.writeln();</script>";
  ?>
```

how could I assign this total distance value in to $tot value.

Comment: PHP is server-side, JavaScript is (generally) client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting confused by two languages being present. You forget that your Javascript will run on the client, in the browser. PHP will run on the server. The only way to get the JavaScript value to your server is to HTTP POST/GET it to the server, using a hidden field in a HTTP form or an via ajax call.

Comment: Thank you Ali, but aim not familiar with ajax, If you can please give me small explanation how could i do this ?? thank you lot

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of is to use JavaScript to send the URL back with a parameter in it such as:

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1

... By using something like this, you can apply it in JavaScript:

```
window.location.href="index.php?value=1";
```

Then in the PHP code use `$_GET`:

```
$somevar = $_GET["value"]; //puts the uid varialbe into $somevar
```

Comment: with this, are we can assign this value in to php variable without reloading the page?

Comment: I'm afraid without refresh you cannot do this.

Comment: @ChathurangaGammanpila, it actually is possible to do something like this without a reload.  Check my answer.  You'd need to implement something called Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript we are presented with here is client-side...

Since PHP is on  the server-side level, we'd have to reach for it via HTTP requests.  HTTP requests is basically communication between the client and server.

JavaScript had a handly little library implemented into it called Ajax, which stands for **Asynchronous** JavaScript and <s>XML</s> (XML isn't really important here).

Ajax allows us to perform HTTP requests asynchronously with in the script, and use the response that the server has as well.

To make thing's syntactically more understandable, I'll be using [jQuery, which provides an easy-to-use Ajax library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...

With this provided, you can construct a request and also handle the response fairly easily......  Lets try this for example:

```
$.ajax({
  "url": "index.php",
  "type": "POST",
  "data": {"testing":true},
  "success": function(response){
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

This provided, we take our `index.php` file, and say we had the following code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["testing"])) {
    echo $_POST["testing"] ? "Hello" : "Goodbye";    
  }
?>
```

Now back to the Ajax function....  In the `"success"` handler, we tell it to log whatever the response is....  Since our PHP is designed to say either `"Hello"` or `"Goodbye"` based on the value of the `"testing"` data we sent, this would provide a pretty straight-forward response...  And in our case, it would log `"Hello"`.

That shows how you can create a relationship between the client and server through Ajax, allowing us to exchange data back and forth more easily.

Comment: Thank you Jamen, I am  not familiar with ajax, By the way, is that right, if I use this $.ajax() under the total variable inside the computeTotalDistance() function